# learner.recorder.plot() raises attribute errror for "plot"

Tags: python, pytorch, image-classification, fast-ai, learning-rate

I'm new to neural network, I'm using fast.ai to train a Cifar10 dataset using residual neural network.
After running `learner.lr_find()`, I tried plotting it using `learner.recorder.plot()`,
But then it raised an `Attribute error: 'wideResNet' object has no attribute 'plot'`

```py
wideResNet = myResidualNeuralNetworkFunction
```

Please, how do I solve this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The FastAI V2 does not have the `.plot()` method, when you call `learner.lr_find()`, you get the plot automatically with the suggested learning rate. Nevertheless, if you still need to intentionally make the plot use `learn.recorder.plot_lr_find()` instead. See more in the docs [here](https://docs.fast.ai/callback.schedule.html?q=plot_lr_#recorder.plot_lr_find)